# How can I set a style property value depending on another style property?

Tags: wpf, triggers

I am currently trying to create a style for my controls which changes the appearance of controls depending on the read-only state of the control.

I have the trigger working properly, but I would like to change some properties depending on the value of other properties.

As an example, take the TextBox control, here is the base style trigger I defined :

```
<TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,3,3,3" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```

The style works fine, and the TextBox renders with a style close to a TextBlock when in read-only mode. But I would like to define the value of the `Padding` property depending on the initial values of `Padding` and `BorderThickness`.

How can I achieve this style ?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351635/can-my-wpf-style-setter-use-a-templatebinding. Try to use the resolution there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - a `Setter`'s value must be a constant.

You probably want to change the template of the `TextBox` when it is read-only, whereupon you can use a `TemplateBinding` to access the assigned value of `Padding`.

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                <TextBlock  Padding="{Binding Padding, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Alternatively, look at whether you can just set the border color to be transparent so that it occupies the same space but is invisible.