# path.fill templatebinding in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, templatebinding

The below xaml works fine:

```
    <Style x:Key="TopButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Path Data="{StaticResource TopCube}" >
                        <Path.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="#414042" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="Canvas.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="{StaticResource HoveredGradient}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Path.Style>
                    </Path>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But when I replace Value="#414042" by Value="{TemplateBinding Background}" I get an error 'Background is not recognized. When I change it to Value="{TemplateBinding Button.Background}" it compiles fine, but I get a runtime XAMLparseException on Setter.Value

What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can my WPF Style Setter use a TemplateBinding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351635/can-my-wpf-style-setter-use-a-templatebinding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case if you want to get default `Button.Background` you need to use `TemplatedParent` binding

```
<Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
```

Comment: It worked even UWP platform, me even the intellisense get lost with the relativesource relativesource anyway thanks a lot!