# 'IndependentValue' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name in chartinToolkit wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, charts, tooltip, wpftoolkit

i am trying to view the value of aces in my chart but i have the following error 
"'IndependentValue' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name in chartinToolkit wpf  "

this is my code

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfToolkitChart.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1031" Width="855" xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"  FlowDirection="RightToLeft">

<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,-28,0,28">
    <Grid Height="500">

        <chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart" Title="Line Series Demo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="33,6,6,0" Height="440" Foreground="DarkRed" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" FontFamily="CPalatineLinoType">
            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries  DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>

            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <StackPanel Margin="2,2,2,2">
                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding IndependentValue}" FontSize="12"/>
                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding DependentValue}"   FontSize="12"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

please cany any one help me in this
thanks :)

Comment: the problem was mostly in xaml i solved it thx :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i had solved the problem by this code

```
<chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:DataPoint">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0077CC" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="1">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <StackPanel Margin="2,2,2,2">
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding IndependentValue}" ContentStringFormat="Date : {0}"/>
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding DependentValue}" ContentStringFormat="Count : {0:###,###,###}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <Ellipse StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
```

Comment: If anyone doesn't understand this solution, it is because the question author tried to use a `TemplateBinding` outside of a `ControlTemplate`, where this special kind of binding is supposed to be used. This solution was therefore, to use it within a `ControlTemplate`.

Answer (score 22):

Just in case someone lands here searching for the error message, I was getting it simply because I was mistakenly using `x:Static` instead of `StaticResource` to access a locally declared resource.

Hope this helps someone down the road.

Comment: My head hurts from banging it against my keyboard after reading your answer. Made my day :-)

Comment: In my case it was a missing `TargetType` prop on a style declaration...

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone needs glasses, like me..

Before (failing XAML)

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{x:Static local:Map:ZoomCommand}" />
```

After (fixed XAML)

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{x:Static local:Map.ZoomCommand}" />
```

I just needed to change the colon to a dot.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because you are using a [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension) outside of a control template. You can only use that binding type within a control template.

Without adding more detail to the question, I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve.

You can see an example of appropriate `TemplateBinding` use at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3095251/1688738).